# under and sub categories in mysql tables (coldfusion,mysql)

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a question regarding ColdFusion and Mysql. I have two tables: PRODUCT and PRODUCT_CAT. I want to list the categories that contains some of the special products that are marked as: `IS_EXTRANET=1`. So I wrote this query:

```
<cfquery name="get_product_cat" datasource="#dsn1#">
    SELECT PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PC.HIERARCHY
    FROM PRODUCT_CAT PC LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
    WHERE P.IS_EXTRANET=1
    GROUP BY PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.HIERARCHY
    ORDER BY PC.HIERARCHY,PC.PRODUCT_CAT
</cfquery>
```

**and the output:**

```
<select name="product_catid">
    <option value="">All Categories</option>
    <cfoutput query="get_product_cat">
          <option value="#product_catid#" <cfif isdefined("attributes.product_catid") and len(attributes.product_catid) and (attributes.product_catid eq product_catid)>selected</cfif>><cfloop from="2" to="#listlen(hierarchy,'.')#" index="pc">&nbsp;&nbsp;</cfloop>#product_cat#</option>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
```

But there is a problem. Inside the `product_cat` table, there are 2 types of categories: "under" and "sub". So inside each "under" category, there are no products, but there are "sub" categories. When I try to list the categories that are only have products with the `is_extranet=1` definition, there are no "under" categories listed. But I want the "under" categories listed too. In other words, if inside the "sub" category is a product with the definition `is_extranet=1`, then show the "under" category, then its subcategories with these products. I hope I was clear :)

Plus, the hierarchy for "under" category looks like this: 100 and for sub: 100.001

Comment: Sorry, you're not very clear. Which tables have UNDER and SUB ? Ideally you would put some test data and the corresponding result in the question.

Comment: @grahamj42 in product_cat, it is named in that way, because it has product's categories, and there no such divisions like under and sub, just hierarchy difference, thus different order by hierarchy

Comment: So if the query selects a row with PC.HIERARCHY=100.001 you want to include the the rows with PC.HIERARCHY=100 ? Is this a character field NNN.NNN or a numeric field ?

Comment: @grahamj42 1) yes, exactly 2) nvarchar

Comment: Have a look at the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24bb7/1). I put *your* query in and data which corresponds to my understanding of the problem, and it worked. Perhaps you could edit the fiddle and reply with the new URL in a comment - you might even solve the problem yourself!

Comment: @grahamj42 have a look at it now, ur data was wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3573d/1 u can see the under category is not displayed, i cannot solve it, im trying, that is why im asking it here

Comment: Thanks for looking at this quickly. So HIERARCHY=200.001 can have a different PRODUCT_CATID from HIERARCHY=200 ?

Comment: @grahamj42 ofcourse, that is why i can't understand how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis that PC.HIERARCHY is unique, this works for me:

```
SELECT PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PC.HIERARCHY
  FROM PRODUCT_CAT PC
  WHERE LEFT(PC.HIERARCHY,3) IN 

  (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(PC.HIERARCHY,3)
    FROM PRODUCT_CAT PC
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
    WHERE P.IS_EXTRANET=1)

GROUP BY PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.HIERARCHY
ORDER BY PC.HIERARCHY,PC.PRODUCT_CAT;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PC.HIERARCHY
  FROM PRODUCT_CAT PC
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT LEFT(PC.HIERARCHY,3) AS UPPER
    FROM PRODUCT_CAT PC
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
    WHERE P.IS_EXTRANET=1) AS H
    ON LEFT(PC.HIERARCHY,3)=H.UPPER 
GROUP BY PC.PRODUCT_CATID,PC.PRODUCT_CAT,PC.HIERARCHY
ORDER BY PC.HIERARCHY,PC.PRODUCT_CAT;
```

I'm not sure which will give better performance. The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3573d/5)

Comment: but there is a little problem, it sort out only the under categories, not sub ones, because if there is a product with `is_extranet=1` in one of the sub category, then all the sub categories of this under category are displayed :) hope it was clear )) any way i solved it by using `union all`